# QTreeView item's editor position problem?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QTreeView` widget in which I have set indentation to `0` with `QTreeView::setIndentation(0)`, but when editing an item, the editor still appears at the indentation level of the default indented behaviour:
[image]

I have tried changing the editor position with a `QStyledItemDelegate::updateEditorGeometry`'s method, but it seems that there is a limit to where I can move the editor horizontally, as I cannot move it to a negative offset, past the `x == 0` position, like for example `QRect(-50, 0, 100, 30)`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

P.S.:
Here is an attempt of a `minimal-reproducible-example`, but this has another bug: the editor widget does not display when the geometry of the widget in `drawRow` is changed! The editor works when typing and pressing enter, it's just not displayed! I'll try to figure out what's the difference between my example in the image above and this code.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sip


class MyTreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        self.setHeaderLabels(["Items"])
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.header().setVisible(False)
        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
        
        self.add_items()
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.click)
    
    def click(self, item, column):
        item.setFlags(
            Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable |
            Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled |
            Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable
        )
        index = self.indexFromItem(item, 0)
        self.edit(index)
    
    def drawRow(self, painter, option, index):
        model = self.model()
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
        widget = self.itemWidget(item, 0)
        if widget is not None:
            geo = QRect(widget.geometry())
            geo.setX(geo.x() + 50)
            widget.setGeometry(geo) # <- This line causes the editor's horizontal offset

        super().drawRow(painter, option, index)
    
    def add_items(self):
        items = [
            'Cookie dough',
            'Hummus',
            'Spaghetti',
            'Dal makhani',
            'Chocolate whipped cream'
        ]

        parent = None
        for item in items:
            new_item = QTreeWidgetItem(None)
            if parent is not None:
                new_item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
            else:
                self.addTopLevelItem(new_item)
            new_item.setText(0, item)
            new_item.setExpanded(True)
            parent = new_item
        
        def edit_last_item(*args):
            new_item.setFlags(
                Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable |
                Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled |
                Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable
            )
            index = self.indexFromItem(new_item, 0)
            self.edit(index)
            print("Editing")
        
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, edit_last_item)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(MyTreeWidget())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: you should add your code as [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying to create a minimal reproducible example as @Parisa.H.R mentioned in the comment, I discovered that in the `drawRow` method in the `QTreeView`/`QTreeWidget` there is some code that adjusts the geometry of item widgets, like so (Python/PyQt example):

```py
class MyTreeView(QTreeView):

    def drawRow(self, painter, option, index):
        model = self.model()
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
        widget = self.itemWidget(item, 0)
        
        geo = ... # <- Code that calculates new geometry
        widget.setGeometry(geo) # <- This line causes the editor's horizontal offset
        
        super().drawRow(painter, option, index)
```

which is what causes the editor widget to be moved horizontally to the right.

Thanks @Parisa.H.R

Comment: I've never encountered this issue. Is the code above an "interpretation" of the C++ code of the Qt sources, or is it part of your own override? Without an MRE (as asked above), it's really hard to understand if this is a bug, or it's caused by a wrong implementation of the override on your part.